# Remove/Change the WPF "- (Not Responding)" text at the top of the window?

Tags: c#, wpf

So I have a C# WPF app that runs a report from a report server, and edits the result to display in Chrome.

Because of the size of the database and the speed of the report server the process always hangs when executing the report (the ReportExecutionService.Render() method).

This causes the app so freeze up and display "- (Not Responding)" in the window title.

It always does this and it always works after a few minutes so really I'd like to just stop this from happening, or maybe even change the message to "- (Loading Report)" to better represent what is actually happening.

Is this possible?

Comment: Move the report-generation code to a background thread so the UI thread isn't blocked and optionally show some kind of progress display on-screen.

Comment: As an aside, if a SQL query takes a long time to execute you should look at why it's slow and if you need to refactor the query at all, what indexes (if any) are being used, and if you should recalculate a table's stored statistics. Take a look at the execution plans.

Comment: Thank you @Dai got it working using a new thread. Also I totally agree with the SQL and checking indexing etc. Unfortunately I'm not allowed to make any changes but I will raise a request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use another thread to code the report-generation code. Then the UI thread isn't blocked

```
new Thread(() =>
{
  Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground = true;
   // your code here 

 }).Start();
```

Comment: Perfect! Works a treat. I've also changed the Window title and cursor arrow to let users know what's happening.

Comment: @SamuelO'Connor ok.. happy to hear my solution works.. keep coding. have a nice day.

Answer (score 2):

Make it Async!

```
public Task DatabaseActionAsync(string argument)
{
    return Task.Run(() => 
        DatabaseAction(argument));
    );
}
```

And wherever you call it:

```
await DatabaseActionAsync(argument);
```